# How to prove that H is a subgroup of G.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices

Let $G$ be a group of all $2 \times 2$ matrices of the form $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b\\
        c & d\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
where determinant $ad-bc \ne 0$ under matrix multiplication and let $H$ be $$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        0 & d \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
 and $ad \ne 0$.
Prove that $H$ is subgroup of $G$.

Answer (score 2):

If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, you must first show that $H\subset G$. Afterwards you must show that $H$ satisfies the following:

1. The identity element of $G$ must be in $H$, i.e. $\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \in H$ which is easily seen as $1\cdot 1 \neq 0$
2. For any matrix $A \in H$ also $A^{-1}\in H$ where $A^{-1}$ denotes the matrix inverse of $A$
3. For any $A,B\in H$ also the product $AB\in H$.

If $H$ satisfies all, it is indeed a subgroup of $G$. 
Start with that, and see where you can go!